# it possible to make your bot change its own nickname once it enters a new server?

Tags: javascript, discord.js, bots

For example, the name of the bot would be Eber™, and as soon as it enters a new server it would automatically change the nickname and put only "Eber"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it's most definitely possible. Just use the the `guildCreate` event which is fired when your bot joins a server. You can see more on what the `Client` class can do in this doc: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client

As for changing the nickname, you can do something like this:

```js
client.on("guildCreate", guild => {
    console.log("Joined a new guild: " + guild.name);
    guild.members.get(bot.user.id).setNickname("some nickname");
})
```

More documentation on changing the nickname if you need it: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember?scrollTo=setNickname

Comment: Note: Instead of `guild.members.get(bot.user.id)` you can use `guild.me`.